# Given $f$ find $θ$ and show that $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0=0.$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

> Given the function: $f(x)=xe^x+\sin(θ), x\le0$ and $f(x)=x\ln x+θ, x>0$ which is continuous.
>
> **I)** Show that $θ=0.$
>
> **II)** Show that $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0=0.$

**Personal work:**

**I)** Because $f$ is continuous (hypothesis) then it applies:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}{f(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}{f(x)}=f(0). (1)$$
•$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}{f(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}(xe^x+\sin(θ))=\dots=\sin(θ)$

•$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}{f(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}{(x\ln x+θ)}=\dots=θ$

•$f(0)=0*e^0+\sin(θ)=\cdots=\sin(θ)$

So, (1) is equals to:

$$\sin(θ)=θ=\sin(θ)\iff \sin(θ)=θ-\sin(θ)\iff 2\sin(θ)=θ \iff \sin(θ)={θ\over 2}$$

The problem? How can I correctly compute $\sin(θ)={θ \over 2}$

Comment: I don't understand how you obtain $\sin(\theta)=\theta-\sin(\theta)$ from $\theta=\sin(\theta)$ . Can you explain ?

Comment: At some point you can see: $\sin(\theta)=\theta-\sin(\theta) \iff 2\sin(\theta)=\theta$ and then I divided by 2. So, we have: $\sin(\theta)={\theta \over 2}.$

Comment: Yes but you do you obtain $\sin(\theta)=\theta-\sin(\theta)$ ?

Comment: @Delta-u Well I just plugged in the results of the limits into $(1)$ so I got a triple equality.

Comment: Yes but I don't understand why $a=b=c$ implies that $a=b-c$.

Comment: @Delta-u I guessed this is how it should be. Anyways, $f(0)=\sin(\theta)$ so, by just using the second limit we get: $\theta=\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76153/discussion-between-alexander-voliotis-and-delta-u).

Answer (score 1):

First observe that since $x e^x + sin(\theta)$ is continuous and defines f on $x \geq 0$, you only need to worry about $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = f(0)$.

This gives you $sin(\theta) = \theta$ as you correctly computed, then observe this implies $\theta=0$. In particular, the only intersection of the curves $\sin t$ and $t$ is at the origin. (Formally you could argue that any solution must be in $[-1,1]$, and use a calculus argument to demonstrate that no other roots exist).